# How can I set stroke-width on a path after it's been transformed?

Tags: svg

I have an SVG file of the form:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <path d="M0.0 0.0 L1.0 0.0 L1.0 1.0 L0.0 1.0 L0.0 0.0 Z" fill="none" transform="translate(276.53762663809374, 97.7838427947598) scale(177.52243125896803, -89.004366812227)" style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 0.5px;"></path>
</svg>
```

The image displays with a huge black border when I want it to show up with a 0.5px border. How can I get the stroke-width to apply after the transform? If this isn't possible, what's the easiest way to wrap the element so that it displays correctly? I'd like to avoid modifying the "d" attribute.

Answer (score 5):

You could use vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <path vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" d="M0.0 0.0 L1.0 0.0 L1.0 1.0 L0.0 1.0 L0.0 0.0 Z" fill="none" transform="translate(276.53762663809374, 97.7838427947598) scale(177.52243125896803, -89.004366812227)" style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 0.5px;"></path>
</svg>
```

One caveat is that IE9/10 don't implement this but Webkit, Opera and Firefox do.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to support IE9+.

Comment: "vector-effect" is defined in SVG Tiny 1.2 which is a later variant of SVG that not all renderers support. Really your only solution is to do what markE suggested and scale your line width down by the same amount that you scale up.